# Cambiar el color de texto de una fila específica de un JTable

Tags: java, java-swing

Quisiera saber cómo cambiar el color del texto de una fila específica de un `JTable`. O sea, tengo varias filas en la tabla y en la última celda de cada fila se encuentra su estado (Egreso/Ingreso), si dice "Egreso" en la última celda de la fila todo el texto de esa fila se cambia a color rojo, en cambio si es "Ingreso" a color azul.

Comparto lo que he estado intentando, pero me genera error al abrir el formulario.

```
void pintarFilas() {
    int row = tbDocTransferir.getColumnCount();
    String toe = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(row, 16);
    if (toe == "Egreso") {
        tbDocTransferir.setForeground(Color.RED);
    }
}
```

Comment: Si con "generar un error" te refieres a una excepción, deberías compartirla. Si te refieres a que el resultado que ves no es lo que esperaste, deberías describir lo que ves y lo que esperaste. Además podrías ser un poco más preciso en declarar que es que en tu pregunta, asumo que `tbDocTransferir` es tu `JTable`?

Comment: No sé si está asociado directamente a tu problema, pero estás haciendo comparación de cadenas con `==` cuando debe ser con `equals`. En tu caso, te recomendaría incluso que hagas la comparación usando `equalsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 1):

No sé que es el error a que te refieres, pero para empezar, asumiendo que `tbDocTransferir` es tu tabla, no tratas de cambiar el color de la celula seleccionada, pero el color de la tabla misma.

El método `setForeground(Color color)` es heredado de `JComponent` y no garantiza que el "look and feel" respeta los argumentos, en el caso de la tabla es muy probable que no va hacer lo que intentas hacer.

Hacía el misterioso error que todavía no compartiste, me imagino que lo siquiente te va solucionar por lo menos eso:

```
    // adivinando que tu tabla probablemente tiene 16 columnas, trata:
    String toe = (String) tbDocTransferir.getValueAt(row, 15);
```

**correctura**

Pensandolo bien, es más probable que `tbDocTransferir`es el `TableModel` de la tabla. Si es así, no sorprende que no funciona de cambiar el color del modelo.